Can not test shadcn input otp component with Jest
I'm creating an OTP page using Shadcn Input-OTP.
Before importing input-otp component. All tests are running fine.
But when it tries to run this component. it gives:
ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined Jest

Minimal Reproductive Example
test cases are in the same directory. (to see the difference comment out the input import)
I've tried mocking resizeObserver or adding it as a global variable.
I've tried this issue on GitHub entirely.
I've tried this answered question on SO
But it gives me new errors:
TypeError: _.observe is not a function Jest


Adding following in test setup file will resolved issue for me


import ResizeObserver from "resize-observer-polyfill";

....

global.ResizeObserver = ResizeObserver;



